# Which approach can I use to generate text based on multiple inputs?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, python, generative-model

I have a little experience in building various models, but I've never created anything like this, so just wondering if I can be pointed in the right direction.

I want to create (in python) a model which will generate text based on multiple inputs, varying from text input (vectorized) to timestamp and integer inputs.

For example, in the training data, the input might include:

`eventType = ShotMade`

`shotType = 2`

`homeTeamScore = 2`

`awayTeamScore = 8`

`player = JR Smith`

`assist = George Hill`

`period = 1`

and the output might be (possibly minus the hashtags):
`JR Smith under the basket for 2! 8-4 CLE. #NBAonBTV #ThisIsWhyWePlay #PlayByPlayEveryDay #NBAFinals`

or

`JR Smith out here doing #WhateverItTakes to make Cavs fans forgive him. #NBAFinals`

Where is the best place to look to get a good knowledge of how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, text generators work by modeling the joint distribution of the text by its Bayesian forward decomposition

$
\begin{align*}  
p(w_1, w_2, ..., w_n) &= p(w_1) * p(w_2|w_1) * p(w_3|w_2, w_1) *\ ...\ * p(w_n|\{w_i\}_{i<n})\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n p(w_i|\{w_k\}_{k<i})\\  
\end{align*}
$

From a modeling perspective, this looks right up RNN's ally, where you can have a state holding information from $\{w_k\}_{k<i}$ to learn a representation of $w_i$

Now, in your specific case, you're interested in a conditional text-generator, so you are trying to model $p(w_1, w_2, ..., w_n | \{v_j\}_j)$, but this same tactic works.

$
\begin{align*}  
p(w_1, w_2, ..., w_n| \{v_j\}_j) &= p(w_1|\{v_j\}_j) * p(w_2|w_1, \{v_j\}_j) * p(w_3|w_2, w_1, \{v_j\}_j) *\ ...\ * p(w_n|\{w_i\}_{i<n}, \{v_j\}_j)\\
&= \prod_{i=1}^n p(w_i|\{w_k\}_{k<i}, \{v_j\}_j)\\  
\end{align*}
$

So, in your RNN or forward-based model, you can use the exact same approach just additionally embed the conditional inputs you have and somehow infuse it into the model (in practice, I have seen this through attention, concatenation, or some other common approach).

My recommendation (depending on the computational power you have) is to take advantage of the recent fad of pre-trained language models. Specifically, ones trained on next word prediction will probably do the job best. A good example is [gpt-2](https://d4mucfpksywv.cloudfront.net/better-language-models/language-models.pdf), and, if you check out their GitHub, their code is very readable and easy to adjust for adding conditional input in the ways I have described.